# textarea does not auto focus even when set to auto focus

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```
<textarea
  className="input"
  ref={textarea_ref}
  name="the-textarea"
  id="the-textarea"
  maxLength="150"
  placeholder="see guidelines for suggestions..."
  autoFocus
  onChange={(e) => input_text(e.target.value)}
  value={validated_text}
></textarea>
```

What might be some other factors that will cause the textarea to not auto focus when initialized?

Comment: are you using any frameworks? Is it react?

Comment: @free_lions_n_tigers_from_cages Does this solves your Problem :  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_textarea_autofocus

Comment: It looks like you're using React, and you absolutely need to mention that, because React is _not_ HTML, even if it _looks_ like HTML.

Comment: yes, it is react.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **autofocus is defined to work reliably only on page load**

So it might not work as you expected in Reactjs Component where you are changing/updating DOM or open a new Modal.

---

**I would suggest using useRef instead:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const textarea_ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    textarea_ref.current.focus();
  });
  return (
    <textarea
      className="input"
      ref={textarea_ref}
      name="the-textarea"
      id="the-textarea"
      maxLength="150"
      placeholder="see guidelines for suggestions..."
    ></textarea>
  );
}
```